# Sourcing MDX files to programmatically create portfolio pages in Gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I'm a newbie trying to build a Gatsby site that programmatically generates pages for MDX files placed at `/content/portfolio` using the following url structure: `sitename/portfolio/single-portfolio-item`. The site is running on the `gatsby-starter-blog-theme`.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. Create a new gatsby site: `gatsby new gatsby-portfolio https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog-theme` and start the server with `gatsby develop`.
2. Create a directory for portfolio MDX posts: `content/portfolio`
3. create a portfolio post: `content/portfolio/pf1.mdx` with the following content:

```
---
title: Portfolio item 1ˆ
date: 2019-04-15
image: ./sunset-beach.jpg
imageAlt: A beach at sunset with crashing waves.
---

Hello, world! This is a demo post for `gatsby-theme-blog`.

Delete me, and get writing!
```

4. Edited `gatsby-config.js` so the files at `content/portfolio` get processed by adding the following lines within the plugins secion:

```
  {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `portfolio`,
        path: `${__dirname}/content/portfolio/`,
      },
```

5. Stopped the server and run `gatsby develop` again
6. Looked for the portfolio post within GraphiQL at `allMdx` and found it there:

```
{
  "data": {
    "allMdx": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "slug": "hello-world/"
        },
        {
          "slug": "my-second-post"
        },
        {
          "slug": "pf1/"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

But here I got stuck.

Like I said, when checking GraphiQL I can see the new post at `allMdx`, but **not at `allMdxBlogPosts`**. I don't know why it's not there and, therefore, why the post isn't getting rendered on the front-end.

And I don't know either how to create an `allPortfolioPosts` node and render its posts on the front-end.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the issue? `allMdx` contains your data so, why do you want `allMdxBlogPosts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the behavior I wanted editing the `gatsby-node.js` file like this:

```js
const { createFilePath } = require("gatsby-source-filesystem")

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions
  
  if (node.internal.type === "Mdx") {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })
    const parent = getNode(node.parent);

    createNodeField({
      name: "slug",
      node,
      value: `${value}`,
    })
    createNodeField({
      name: `sourceName`,
      node,
      value: parent.sourceInstanceName
    });
  }
}
const path = require("path")

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
      allMdx {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            fields {
              slug
              sourceName
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild('  ERROR: Loading "createPages" query')
  }

  const posts = result.data.allMdx.edges

  posts.forEach(({ node }, index) => {
    createPage({
      path: `${node.fields.sourceName}${node.fields.slug}`,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/components/posts-page-layout.js`),
      context: { id: node.id },
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're making data queryable, but never querying it to create pages. One way to do this is with the [file system route API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/file-system-route-api/).

Inside your pages directory make a file like: `{Mdx.slug}.js`. That file will generate a page (accessible at localhost:8000/) for each Mdx Node you have and give you access to that Node's id.

So you can do something like this:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import { MDXRenderer } from "gatsby-plugin-mdx"
import Layout from "../../components/layout"

const BlogPostPage = ({data}) => {
  const post = data.mdx
  return (
    <Layout>
      <article>
        <h2>{post.frontmatter.title}</h2>
        <MDXRenderer>{post.body}</MDXRenderer>
      </article>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query BlogPostById($id: String) {
    mdx(id: { eq: $id }) {
      body
      frontmatter {
        title
      }
    }
  }
`

export default BlogPostPage
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already found another solution. But I'll try your suggestion too. The file system API is something I haven't tried yet and I want to give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that `allMdx` is the common way to retrieve `.mdx` data. To create a and display it in the front end, just:

```
const path = require("path")

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions, reporter }) => {
  // Destructure the createPage function from the actions object
  const { createPage } = actions

  const result = await graphql(`
    query {
      allMdx {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild('  ERROR: Loading "createPages" query')
  }

  // Create blog post pages.
  const posts = result.data.allMdx.edges

  // you'll call `createPage` for each result
  posts.forEach(({ node }, index) => {
    createPage({
      // This is the slug you created before
      // (or `node.frontmatter.slug`)
      path: node.fields.slug,
      // This component will wrap our MDX content
      component: path.resolve(`./src/components/posts-page-layout.js`),
      // You can use the values in this context in
      // our page layout component
      context: { slug: node.fields.slug },
    })
  })
}
```

What's happening here is that you don't need to create a custom node object to get all the data, by default, the `.mdx` implementation does it for you. `allMdx` contains your data so use it to create your pages. The `slug` is the identifier parameter passed via context to the template as well as the slug.

Then in your `posts-page-layout.js`, something like this should work:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import { MDXProvider } from "@mdx-js/react"
import { MDXRenderer } from "gatsby-plugin-mdx"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

const shortcodes = { Link } // Provide common components here

export default function PageTemplate({ data: { mdx } }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{mdx.frontmatter.title}</h1>
      <MDXProvider components={shortcodes}>
        <MDXRenderer>{mdx.body}</MDXRenderer>
      </MDXProvider>
    </div>
  )
}

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query BlogPostQuery($slug: String) {
    mdx(id: { eq: $slug }) {
      id
      body
      frontmatter {
        title
      }
    }
  }
`
```

With the `slug` provided, you can make a custom query for each post to retrieve each data and print it in the front end.

Resources:

- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-mdx/
- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/mdx/programmatically-creating-pages/
- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/mdx/getting-started/
- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/mdx/